# How to switch keyboard with layout on android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, keyboard

Im creating application and I want to do one thing. Twitter app and Viber have very awesome feature. When you click on bottom icon like (map) on twitter appears map and when you click on edittext then appears keyboard on that map, at that position, without blink and no lag. I created the same but whe i click icon "map" keyboard hide:

**imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);**

and call:

**person_company_add_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);**

SCREEN BLINK..  How can I solve this problem?

my listener of clicking:

View.OnClickListener clickHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

```
          public void onClick(View v) {

              imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);

              switch(v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button_add_attachment:
                    attachment_add_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
                case R.id.button_add_pc:

                break;
                case R.id.button_add_location:

                break;
             }

         }
    };
```

Comment: where are you calling setVisibility method? Show some of your code..

Comment: i'm added on all buttons xml onclick method layoutClick(View v), than switch by v.getId() get button ID than visible gone all others layouts and keyboard after that show clicked button layout